# Choosing the best data-sctructure for file storing

Tags: java, data-structures

so
my program gets a directory, filter the files according to different filters, then perform several actions and return the files in a desired order.
i thought it is not necessary to order before i filter because then i would sort a lot of files for nothing. after the files are sorted i return them in a TreeSet.

so, my question is, what would be the best data structure to store the files before i put them in order? by best i mean in terms of run time of course.
thanks, yotam

Comment: Probably ArrayList. You don't have to return a TreeSet: Collections.sort(list) is good enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with iluxa, just use an ArrayList. When you sort then you can use Collections.sort, as iluxa mentioned, but if you have a list of File objects (as opposed to just file name Strings) then you will need pass through a second parameter to the sort method. This will be an anonymous subclass of Comparator, something like the below:

```
Collections.sort(listOfDateObjects, new Comparator<File>() {

     @Override
     public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
         // put your comparison logic here
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple array should be fine.  As you loop through the array of files, anything that passes your filters add to your `TreeSet` that you will return.

Comment: oh i can't, requirements says first filter then add to treeSet

Comment: @yota,  That is still filtering before you add it to the set.  If there is a requirement you haven't mentioned yet, please update your question.